# Wamp in network with a domain name

Tags: dns, wamp, wampserver

I have configured a Wamp server in my local network and it works great. I can access each project with xxx.xxx.xxx/myproject, but, as another option, can I configure them to access like www.myproject.com or http://myproject.com **from the local network**? I am an embedded system programmer and I have to access my embedded Ethernet boards with various machines. It works fine with an IP address, but I just want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

you can do that by configuring your virtual hosts and the httpd.conf file of your apache

**configure apache**

the file of your apache will be located in:

- c:\wamp\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf

search for something like:

```
DocumentRoot 'c:/wamp/www'
```

and add the following code after the DocumentRoot 'c:/wamp/www' into the file:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www'
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www\ClientsMyClient'
</VirtualHost>
```

**configure hostfile**

on mac via terminal:

- sudo nano /etc/hosts

on windows 7:

- open a texteditor as administrator
- open file and go to: %Systemroot%\System32\Drivers\Etc

(source: [edit hosts file in windows 7](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/edit-hosts-file-in-windows-7-windows-vista/))

when you have it opened just write a new line into the file:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX yourdomain.com
(mostly this will be: 127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com)
```

I do suggest you use yourdomain.local, because if you ever host a website, you might get confused about which one is the public one and which one is the local website :).

in your browser you then type: yourdomain.com and you should be able to have a project hosted on a wamp server, with his own domain.

hope this helps! :-)

(source: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-setup-multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp/)

Answer (score 0):

Open C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
and after that localhost address(127.0.0.1) add the domain name which you want like www.example.com and make a space between ip address and domain name.

For Example, 127.0.0.1 www.example.com

Note: You need to open 'hosts' file in Administrator Privileges .

Answer (score 0):

1. Open C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\conf\httpd.conf
2. Search for something like:

```
    #Virtual hosts
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

3. Uncomment line

```
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

4. Open C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
5. Add the following code in the end:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yourdomain.com
        ServerAlias yourdomain.com
        DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/somename"
        <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/somename/">
            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

6. Go to: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc
7. Open hosts
8. When you have it opened just write a new line into the file:

```
    127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
```

9. Restart WAMP server
10. In your browser you then type: yourdomain.com and you should be able to have a project hosted on a wamp server, with his own domain.